# Why is this python regex not matching any groups?

Tags: python, regex

Helping a friend with some inherited code in a propietary tool.

Neither of us are too familiar with Python or Regex.

In the code below, the degF regex matches 2 groups when I use Pythex (http://pythex.org/) but returns None.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
import re

testString = "Friday: Thundery Shower, Maximum Temperature: 27°C (81°F) Minimum Temperature: 17°C (63°F)"

t = re.match("^([^:]+):\s*([^,]+)", testString)
degF = re.match("^(\d+.F\))", testString)

print t .           # _sre.SRE_Match object
print t.group(1)    # Friday
print t.group(2)    # Thundery Shower
print degF          # None

# print "Max temp " + degF.group(1)
# print "Min temp " + degF.group(2)
```

Comment: `re.match("^(\d+.F\))"` you're looking for temperature at the start of the string.

Comment: Use this if you want to extract temperature's values : `re.findall('(\d+°\w+)', teststring)` or `re.findall('(\d+°[F|C])', a)`

Comment: Your expression works: https://regex101.com/r/RuGgej/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `.` in your pattern to match a degree symbol. However, a `.` matches a single byte, while `°` is in fact two bytes long:

```
print len('°') # => 2
```

So, you may just use `°` instead of `.` in your `degF` pattern (or `\W*` to match zero or more non-word chars, i.e. `r"(\d+\W+F)\)"`), use `re.search` everywhere and remove the `^` if you do not plan to match only at the start of the string:

```
degF = re.findall(r"(\d+°F)\)", testString)
print(degF)                                 # => ['81\xc2\xb0F', '63\xc2\xb0F']
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/xiLuI5)

You may shift the unescaped `)` to right after `\d+` to only match *whole numbers*. You may change `\d` to `\d[\d.]*` to match float or integer numbers.

Comment: Closest yet - just need to work out capturing that second °F value in group(2)

Comment: No, you just want to use `re.findall` then.

Comment: Ah, was initially confused because one returns list, the other returns MatchObject, so different syntax pulling them back out, but got it now, thanks

Comment: Final code for reference - # This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os, sys
import re

testString = "Friday: Thundery Shower, Maximum Temperature: 27°C (81°F) Minimum Temperature: 17°C (63°F)"


t = re.match("^([^:]+):\s*([^,]+)", testString)
#degF = re.findall("(([0-9]+.F))", testString)
degF = re.findall(r"(\d+°F)\)", testString)

print t
print t.group(1) # Friday
print t.group(2) # Thundery Shower
print degF
print
print "Max temp F " + degF[0]
print "Min temp F " + degF[1]

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp here begins with `^` (and additionally `re.match` matches only at the beginning of string), but your `testString` doesn't begin with a sequence of digits.

Comment: Ah, that was a hangover from earlier testing, but even something like (\([0-9]+.F\)) isn't working

Comment: @Rob, Even if you use `re.search`?

Comment: degF = re.search("(\([0-9]+.F\))", testString) gives me None

Comment: @RobCowell: This works as well: https://regex101.com/r/RuGgej/2, there must be sth. different here.

Comment: Use `r"(\d+°F\))"`

Comment: Is that Python 2? If yes, use `flag=re.UNICODE` in `search`.

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains characters out of the ASCII range that are encoded with two bytes (in UTF-8), but your string isn't defined as an unicode string and the grapheme `°` is seen as 2 different characters.

If you want the dot to match `°` as a single grapheme, you need to define your string as a unicode string:

```
testString = u"Friday: Thundery Shower, Maximum Temperature: 27°C (81°F) Minimum Temperature: 17°C (63°F)"
```

Then the pattern `\d+.F` will match without any problem.